# What does it smell like? or How does it smell?

Tags: word-choice

> What does it smell like?
>
> How does it smell?

I think both of them are correct ways of asking what something smells like. But I feel that there is some difference between them. Can you please point that out?

Comment: Crucially, only the latter works in a "my dog's got no nose..." joke.

Answer (score 11):

The first question asks for a comparison:

> *What does it smell like?*
>
> > Possible answers:
>
> It smells like gingerbread.
> It smells like fruity wine.
> It smells like a cesspool.

The second question asks for a word describing the quality or goodness of the aroma:

> *How does it smell?*
>
> > Possible answers:
>
> It smells great!
> It smells terrible.
> It smells like a cesspool.

Okay, why did I use that last one for both questions? Because everyone knows a cesspool smells awful, so it works for the second question. It's essentially the equivalent of:

> It smells awful – like a cesspool.

Comment: What if I take the question from the first set and the answer from the second? Like, What does it smell like? It smells bad.

Comment: @KaptanSingh That would be an acceptable, if vague, answer and the person asking you might repeat the question with emphasis... on **how** it smells bad. "Bad" is really generic and subjective.  Some people think blue cheese smell "bad" but people who appreciate them like the smell.

Comment: @KaptanSingh - That answer wouldn't be "wrong" – but, then again, it simply wouldn't answer the question as precisely as it could.

Comment: You certainly could switch answers from group 1 to group 2. Though I suppose this doesn't prove much, as people often "answer" a question with a statement that does not really directly answer the question. Example: "How long have you known Sally?" A direct answer would be a period of time, like "Five years". But if someone said, "We met in college", few would say that is non-responsive. This is especially true if the question has a flawed premise. "How long have you known Sally?" "I don't know anyone named Sally."

Comment: Anyway, I think I got off track. A question like, "What does it smell like?" MIGHT be asking for a  literal response: "It smells like a grapefruit", etc. But often the question is very general, and, "Oh, it smells very pretty" would be a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: Just to be nitpicky: In the context of a discussion of biology, the correct answer to "How does it smell?" might be "Through a series of receptors along the lining of the nasal cavity."

Comment: @Jay - I agree there's some degree of interchangeability here. But the O.P. seemed to ask about subtle difference in nuance, which is why I answered the way I did. Still, your comments help tell the complete story.

Comment: @J.R. I wasn't disagreeing with you. Rather, I was trying to elaborate. And I rambled all over the place. Not my best post ever. :-(

Comment: @Jay - I didn't sense you were disagreeing. Rather, I thought you were enhancing my answer, and I appreciated your remarks. :^)